# ActionBar Custom Title Color

Tags: android, android-actionbar, title, textcolor, subtitle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<style name="OmlActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/OmlActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/back_arrow</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/OmlActionBarTitle</item>
    <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/OmlActionBarSubTitle</item>
</style>

<style name="OmlActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/action_bar_white</item>
</style>

<style name="OmlActionBarTitle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/action_bar_blue</item>
</style>

<style name="OmlActionBarSubTitle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/action_bar_blue</item>
</style>
```

Hi,I need to customize my actionBar title Text Color and subTitle Text Color. I used the above style but there is no change.

Answer (score 1):

Try The Following...

**style.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/login_background</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/theme_blue</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTitleText</item>
        <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarSubTitleText</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTitleText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/stdDarkBlueText</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarSubTitleText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/stdDarkBlueText</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Apply this theme to your application in Manifest File..

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon128"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" // apply theme here
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
```

Answer (score 0):

i have done with simple one line code

```
actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ff0000'>ActionBartitle </font>"));
```